# Unstoppable server - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am using an ubuntu machine and rubymine ide. The problem is that I am unable to stop the server which makes the debugg impossible. The app I am working on is exclusively running with ssl security, so listening to the 443 port. I tried everything

when I run `pgrep -l rails`, no such process is found. So I am only able to kill ruby processes, but the server won't stop.

Then I tried `./script/server stop` but it didn't stop the server

I tried `kill -INT $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)` but there is no server.pid file inside `app_root/tmp/pids`

I tried `lsof -wni tcp:3000`, and `lsof -wni tcp:443` : but no output

I tried `killall -9 rails`, but no rails process is found

I tried `CTRL-C` but the server is still running

I tried `fuser -n tcp 3000` and the server is still running

Answer (score 0):

You have to kill allruby processes if any are. THere are no rails process, since rails its just a framework written on ruby, so the ruby does all interpretation

Comment: Thank you for your response I have killed all of them, but server still running ???

Comment: is that question? If so, could you post your `ps aux` before killing all processes and after ?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the process that is running the rails server with the following command. Then use kill to stop the server

```
ps -ef | grep rails
```

Comment: thank you but there's no rails process found, server still running