# RubyMine stop button creates zombie Puma servers in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rubymine, puma

## Related questions/issues not directly addressing this issue

- [Puma won't die when killing rails server with ctrl-c](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1247)
- [Can't kill a process - stopping rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040790/cant-kill-a-process-stopping-rails-server)
- [Unstoppable server - rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176272/unstoppable-server-rails)
- [How to stop/kill server (development) in rubymine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525488/how-to-stop-kill-server-development-in-rubymine)
- [Can't stop rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088163/cant-stop-rails-server)
- [Signal sent by the stopping button](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203374490-Signal-sent-by-the-stopping-button)
- [Send SIGINT signal to running programm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3067)
- [Sending SIGTERM to a server process when running via `rails s` (in clustered mode) fails to stop the server successfully](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1386)
- [Appropriately wait for worker child process when shutting down via SIGTERM](https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/1437)
- [Signal traps exit with status 0 instead of killing own process](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1183)
- [Rails server doesn't stop on windows bash killing](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20101)
- [Rubymine on Windows with WSL based interpreter: Puma fails to kill the server process when it termiinates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20995)
- [WSL process tree survives a taskkill](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2496)
- [[WSL] Rubymine does not kill rails process, need to manually do it.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20751)

## Specifications

- Windows 10 (10.0.17134 Build 17134 with Feature Update 1803) running *Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS* via Windows Subsystem for Linux
- RubyMine 2018.2.3
- Puma 3.12.0
- Rails 5.1.4
- Ruby 2.5.1p57

## Issue

Starting a development environment with the green start arrow in RubyMine starts a Puma server as expected. The server console log shows:

```
]0;Ubuntu^Z
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[2331] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[2331] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Private Caller
[2331] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[2331] * Environment: development
[2331] * Process workers: 2
[2331] * Preloading application
[2331] * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
[2331] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[2331] - Worker 0 (pid: 2339) booted, phase: 0
[2331] - Worker 1 (pid: 2343) booted, phase: 0
```

(Not sure what's with the broken characters around Ubuntu at the top, but that's another issue...)

I can monitor the server by issuing the `ps aux | grep puma` command in console. The output is as follows:

```
samort7   2456 16.9  0.3 430504 66420 tty5     Sl   23:58   0:05 puma 3.9.1 (tcp://127.0.0.1:3000) [rails-sample-app]
samort7   2464  1.6  0.3 849172 54052 tty5     Sl   23:58   0:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 2456 [rails-sample-app]
samort7   2468  1.5  0.3 849176 54052 tty5     Sl   23:58   0:00 puma: cluster worker 1: 2456 [rails-sample-app]
samort7   2493  0.0  0.0  14804  1200 tty4     S    23:59   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

Clicking the red "Stop" button in IntelliJ causes this line to show up in the server console log:

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, running `ps aux| grep puma` again reveals that the puma server is still running:

```
samort7   2464  0.2  0.3 849172 54340 ?        Sl   Oct12   0:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 2456 [rails-sample-app]
samort7   2468  0.2  0.3 849176 54332 ?        Sl   Oct12   0:00 puma: cluster worker 1: 2456 [rails-sample-app]
samort7   2505  0.0  0.0  14804  1200 tty4     S    00:01   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

Repeatedly clicking start and stop will cause more and more zombie processes to be created. These processes can be killed by issuing a `pkill -9 -f puma` command, but that is less than ideal and defeats the whole purpose of the stop button.

## Expected Result

Running the server directly from the terminal with `rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000` starts the server as before and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> gives the following output and doesn't create zombie processes:

```
[2688] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
[2688] === puma shutdown: 2018-10-13 00:12:00 -0400 ===
[2688] - Goodbye!
Exiting
```

## Analysis

According to the [RubyMine documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/interactive-console.html), clicking the stop button:

> invokes *soft kill* allowing the application to catch the `SIGINT` event and perform graceful termination (on Windows, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event is emulated).

Despite what the documentation claims, this does not appear to be happening. It seems that the stop button is actually issuing a `SIGKILL` signal, stopping the process without allowing it to gracefully clean up.

I have also noticed that if I close all terminal windows both inside and outside of RubyMine, then open up a new terminal window, the zombie processes are gone.

## Question

How can I get RubyMine to issue the correct `SIGINT` signal upon pressing the red stop button so that the Puma server can be shut down gracefully without creating zombie processes?

For reference, I am experiencing this issue in [this commit](https://github.com/tliss/rails-sample-app/commit/7ab3cd3ea2dfcc6a7b8e6708bef198a591108e90) of my codebase (a chapter from [Michael Hartle's Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)).